# Showing that $\exp\big(-|x|^p\big)$ is not a characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, characteristic-functions

I need to show that $\exp\big(-|x|^p\big)$ is not a characteristic function of a non negative pdf for $p>2$. I am a bit lost as to how to approach this problem.

Thank in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi (x)=e^{-|x|^{p}}$. Let $X$ be random variable with this  characteristic function. It is easy to see that when $p>2$  $\phi ''(0)$ exists and  $\phi ''(0)=0$. This implies that $EX^{2}=0$. But then $X=0$ almost surely and $\phi (x)=Ee^{itX}=1$ for all $x$. This contradiction shows that there is no random variable with this  characteristic function.